# Why do I need to add the type here, and is there a better way?

Tags: java, generics, types, compiler-errors, java-8

The following code fails to compile,

```
  Validation<String, AdRequest> validateTrackingRequest(final AdRequest request) {
    return request.getTracking().stream()
        .filter(tracker -> tracker.url().length() > URL_CHAR_LIMIT).findAny()
        .map(tracker ->
            Validation.invalid("Tracking URL for event " + tracker.type() + " exceeds "
                               + URL_CHAR_LIMIT + " character limit: " + tracker.url()))
        .orElse(Validation.valid(request));
  }
```

with the error message,

```
Incompatible types. Required: Validation<String, AdRequest>. Found Validation<String, Object>.
```

Experimenting a little bit, I found that adding this weird syntax before the call to `map` solves the issue:

```
        .<Validation<String, AdRequest>>map(tracker ->
```

(I had seen others do this before.)

What kind of syntax is this?

I understand that this happens because the underlying mechanism to `Validation.invalid` must be based on a generic `Object`, and so some sort of cast is necessary. So maybe this syntax is that "cast".

But also, is there a better way to write what I'm doing?

(This is `javaslang` a.k.a. `vavr`'s Validation library.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called method invocation with explicit type arguments. You could go with a less "weird" piece of syntax:

```
Validation.<String, AdRequest>invalid(...)
```

The problem is in how the `Validation.invalid` method defined and what context it's going to be called within.

```
static <E, T> Validation<E, T> invalid(E error)
```

The second generic parameter `T` cannot be determined implicitly since `map` doesn't care about the type of the result.

```
// no context
Validation<String, Object> v1 = Validation.invalid("error");

// the context set explicitly 
Validation<String, AdRequest> v2 = Validation.<String, AdRequest>invalid("error");

// the type is determined by the context implicitly
Validation<String, AdRequest> v3 = Validation.invalid("error");
```

To figure out the type, the context should be present. `Optional.map` doesn't give you this context. It perfectly works with any result type `R` you are passing:

```
// v1 = Validation<String, Object>
Optional<Validation<String, Object>> o1 = ofNullable(null).map(i -> v1);

// v2 = Validation<String, AdRequest>
Optional<Validation<String, AdRequest>> o2 = ofNullable(null).map(i -> v2);
```

It will return you a generalised instance *by the type you provided*. You are giving a `Validation<String, Object>` object, so you are getting `map(Function<..., Validation<String, Object>>)` which confuses `orElse` and contradicts to the return type.

---

It's rather a matter of taste, but I would put some stuff into variables:

```
Validation<String, AdRequest> validateTrackingRequest(AdRequest request) {
    Validation<String, AdRequest> valid = Validation.valid(request);
    Function<Tracker, Validation<String, AdRequest>> mapper = tracker -> Validation.invalid(...);
    Predicate<Tracker> predicate = tracker -> ...;

    return request.getTracking().stream().filter(predicate).findAny().map(mapper).orElse(valid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Java in general. Is there a way I could have written that cleaner perhaps without filter and map and orElse?

Comment: @AndrewCheong, I couldn't come up with a better solution (except for the approach of putting some stuff into variables to clear up the chain - though I am not sure this is making things better)